# Best way to add "columns" to a tf.data.dataset

Tags: dataframe, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

What is the best way (in terms of runtime and best-practice) to add a column to a TensorFlow dataset?

Let's say that `dataset` is a `PrefetchDataset` generated from a CSV via `make_csv_dataset`. I'd like to add a feature column `B` based on a pre-existing feature column `A` of `dataset`.

I tried to adapt the code from [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) tutorial (cf. the function `PackNumericFeatures()`) to create the class

```
class add_column(object):

    def __call__(self, features, labels):

        features['B'] = tf.map_fn(
            lambda x: len(str(x+"postfix")), features['A'])

        return features, labels
```

and then updating the dataset with

```
dataset = dataset.map(add_column())
```

Assuming that the pre-existing feature `A` is a string, this successfully adds `"postfix"` to each string copied from `A`. However, if I want to populate `B` with the length of each element in `A`, then replacing the lambda function with `lambda x: len(x)` gives the error

```
TypeError: len is not well defined for symbolic Tensors. (TensorArrayV2Read/TensorListGetItem:0) Please call `x.shape` rather than `len(x)` for shape information.
```

Similarly, a basic function such as `lambda x: 'a' in x` gives the error

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph is disabled in this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.
```

Adding new columns processed from pre-existing ones is much more easy with pandas DataFrames. What am I doing wrong? Is it even best practice to use `map_fn()` along with classes such as `add_column()`?

Answer (score 2):

y_dataset = x_dataset.map(fn1)

You can define fn1 as you want

```
@tf.function
def fn1(x):
    ##use x to derive additional columns u want. Set the shape as well
    y = {}
    y.update(x)
    y['new1'] = new1
    y['new2'] = new2
    return y
```

Comment: yes thanks - this is simple and actually works.